# How to use remove_if on an std::list of structs when you want to compare to a member variable of the struct

Tags: c++, struct, stdlist, remove-if

I have an `std::list` of structs and I would like to remove items from the list based on if a certain member variable matches a particular value.

My struct and list:

```
struct Foo
{
  uint64_t PID;
  uintptr_t addr;
};

std::list<Foo> FooList;
```

Code to remove entry:

```
uintptr_t Bar;
FooList.remove_if(???) // Remove when "Foo.addr == Bar";
```

I'm not sure how to reference to the struct instance inside of the `remove_if()` function, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Naitzirch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list::remove_if` takes a function object as its argument. You can feed with an inline lambda function like this:

```
FooList.remove_if([Bar] (auto &element) {
    return element.addr == Bar;
});
```

**Edit**: be advised that if `Bar` is a local variable declared outside if the lambda, you need to *capture* it via copy (`Bar`) or reference (`&Bar`) within the lambda capture list (the leading square brackets)

Comment: Awesome! It worked, thanks. Also note the semi-colons on your second and third line ;)

Comment: @Naitzirch nice catch. Fixed

Comment: There shouldn't be a `=` for `=Bar`. It should just be `Bar`. `=` is only used to allow default capture of all used variables.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you are most likely right, since it doesn't have such notation in the reference documents, however Stroustrup uses it in his **A Tour of C++**: *Had we wanted to give the generated object a copy of x, we could have said so: [=x]*. 6.3.3 Lambda Expressions